# Getting ambiguous output from useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I was playing around with React lifecycle methods using hooks, and I got something unexpected, I made a button that will change the state name to 'amritesh', but after changing the name from an empty string to 'amritesh', I will again be able to change it from 'amritesh' to 'amritesh' and that is not how virtual DOM works in react, as per my knowledge.

**How was I able to know that it was changing again?**

By clicking twice on the button, the console prints 'hi' and 'amritesh' again, but it only prints twice after that it won't work.

**Now, the question arises if it changes the same name second time why not for the third time, fourth time, and so on?**

**Codesandbox link** -> https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-jones-p1eeuz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If you want to check when React rendered the component and how many time it rendered then you see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-williams-2evjq2?file=/src/App.js). React won't render component if you pass same state again.

Comment: Then why in my case is it printing twice?

Comment: @DecPK can please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing `console.logs` should usually be done inside `useEffect`.
The reason is, that a component might not re-render, might recalculate only the return statement, etc.

It is also true that if the new state strictly equals the previous one, it won't re render. Strings are primitives, so:

```
'amritesh' === 'amritesh' // true
```

But

```
{d: 3} === {d: 3} // false, different objects in memory, thus re render.
```

In your case, React detects that the previous state equals the new one, and doesn't re-render.

Your name gets printed twice because React needs to compare twice the states. But from the second time, it doesn't re-render.